# Angular Unit testing ControlValueAccessor with ngFor

Tags: angular, jestjs, jasmine, angular-test, angular2-changedetection

How to test ngFor elements when using inside of ControleValueAccessor.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox-group',
  templateUrl: `
<h3 class="tt">s</h3>
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of _model;let i = index" >  <h3>s</h3>
  <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="c{{i}}"/>
  </div>
</ng-container>

`,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckboxGroupComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})

export class CheckboxGroupComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    ref.detach();
  }
  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this._model = value;
    if(value != null) { this.ref.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

And from parent settings.html this controle value accessor is imported:

```
<div>
  <checkbox-group [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"></checkbox-group>
</div>
```

Now when I want to test it, it just has one child element. and just know  tag as first and last child element

setting.spec.ts:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SettingsPage, CheckboxGroupComponent ],
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
          useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckboxGroupComponent),
          multi: true
        }
        // other providers
      ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
}).compileComponents();

it('should get checkBoxGroup Childs', fakeAsync(() => {  
    let customComponent = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('checkbox-group');
    component.selectedItems = [true,true,true];
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      customComponent.NgModule=[true,false,true];
      fixture.detectChanges();
      debugger;        
    }); 
}))
```

debug on customComponent:

[image: debug on customComponent]

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do but try this:

Pay attention to the comments marked !!

```
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
....
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SettingsPage, CheckboxGroupComponent ],
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
      /* !! Get rid of these lines because CheckboxGroupComponent
         is already doing the providing !!
        {
          provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
          useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckboxGroupComponent),
          multi: true
        } */
        // other providers
      ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
}).compileComponents();

it('should get checkBoxGroup Childs', fakeAsync(() => {  
    component.selectedItems = [true,true,true];
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // !! We can queryAll of the CSS elements and expect the length to be 3
    let customComponents = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('checkbox-group'));
    expect(customComponents.length).toBe(3);
}))
```

!! Edit !!

```
<h3 class="tt">s</h3> // <-- this is the h3 you're seeing
<h1>Model's value: </h1>
<pre>{{ _model | json }}</pre>
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of _model;let i = index" >  <h3>s</h3> // You want to see <h3>s</h3>
  <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="c{{i}}"/>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

So are you saying that you only see that h3 with class `tt` and not the h3 with s inside of it?

I added an `h1` and a `pre` tag to show the value of the `_model`. See what the value of it is and make sure it is not an empty array.

Comment: Thank you I'll try this, ControleValueAccessor has a single h1 tag and dynamic elemet checkbox added by ngfor from the _mode. I can get the h1 element but seems the dynamic element didn't load or did not detect change.

Comment: It's not working ;( , customComponents just have one h1 element

Comment: Check out my edit, it should hopefully help you debug the issue.

Comment: I found just ngfor not rendered, I'll check this too.I have to make an stackbliz. Thank you